# What does the metaphor 'bad blood' mean?

Tags: idioms

On reading an academic paper, I encountered the following sentence:

> "Between the neighbors runs bad blood".

This sentence is treated as metaphorical, but I can't guess what it means since no context has been provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad Blood 
- the feelings of hate between people because of arguments in the past (often + between)

For example:

> Police say the arson attack may have been the result of bad blood
>   between the two families.

The sentence :

> "Between the neighbors runs bad blood"

means that there's a hate or an argument between the neighbors.

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you included an external reference such as idioms.thefreedictionary.com (hint hint)